# I can't see my ImageButton on Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

[This is my error photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AkOf.jpg)

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<VideoView
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:background="#c64e4e4e"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="192dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/play" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So I can't see my ImageButton on my emulator. And my photo is png but I can see transparent things on android studio, Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `ImageButton` to:

```
<ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="192dp"
        android:src="@drawable/play" />
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. How can I change my ImageButton resolution?

Comment: Please accept my answer, you have to design the image for different screen sizes

Comment: Okay, I accepted. My Image is png but Android Studio is guess jpg. [Like this](https://vgy.me/s1RK4M.png) How can i fix this?

Comment: Is the problem that your image has a background instead of being transparent?

Comment: Yes. This is my problem.

Comment: Add this in your imageButton --  `android:background="@null"`

Comment: Thank you, Have a nice day.